# How to sort multiple numeric-style citaton call-outs?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, sorting

I am new to Latex. I have finished writing my document. Now I am trying to sort the citations in the main document. Is there a command to do this automatically?

For example:

[image]

I want to have it like this:

Achsen auf [9, 10].

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
d\cite{STA02}
....
Achsen auf\cite{STA01, STA02}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

file `refernces.bib`

```
@misc{STA01,
  title={{Anteil der Lkw an der Transportleistung im Güterverkehr in Deutschland bis 2023}},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{https://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/12195/umfrage/anteil-der-lkw-am-gueterverkehr-in-deutschland/}},
  url={https://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/12195/umfrage/anteil-der-lkw-am-gueterverkehr-in-deutschland/},
  author = {Martin Kords},
  Year      = { 26.05.2020},
}

@misc{STA02,
  title={{Güterverkehr in Deutschland nach Verkehrszweigen 2019}},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{https://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/75784/umfrage/gueterverkehr-in-deutschland-nach-verkehrszweigen/}},
  url={https://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/75784/umfrage/gueterverkehr-in-deutschland-nach-verkehrszweigen/},
  author = {Martin Kords},
  Year      = { 03.09.2020},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how, i.e., with which tools, you create the bibliography and the citation call-outs.

Comment: @Mico I edited my question.

Comment: Please also tell us which citation management package (if any) you load: `natbib`, `cite`, something else?

Comment: \usepackage{natbib}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the numeric-style citation call-outs sorted, you need to load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `sort&compress`:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,<any other options>]{natbib}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!